# Reordering values from highest importance to lowest in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am very new to R and trying to complete a seemingly easy task but I am struggling to get it executed properly. I have a bar chart I created that shows the relative importance of my Random Forest model I have created. I successfully created the chart but would like the most important variables to be at the top and least important near the bottom.

My script is below:

```
 RI<-ggplot(RI,aes(x=X0,y=Property))+geom_col()
  RI<-RI+labs(x="Relative Importance", y="Variable")
RI
```

My table is below:

[image]

I tried following the instructions found here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-order-of-bars-in-bar-chart-in-r/

but wasn't getting a result of reordered data.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a *minimal reproducible* example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  We know your code isn't working, but we don't know what your code is, so it's difficult to suggest changes.

Comment: Also, please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order Bars in ggplot2 bar graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208679/order-bars-in-ggplot2-bar-graph)

Comment: @jpsmith
 Seems useful but I still can't get it to work in my script. I am now getting this error message:   RI<-RI+ggplot(RI,aes(x=X,y=Property))+geom_col()
Error in ggplot(RI, aes(x = X, y = Property)) : 
  could not find function "ggplot"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming unique *Property* values, reordered by giving ordered levels to `factor`

```
ggplot(RI, aes(x=X0, y=factor(Property, levels=Property[order(X0)]))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  labs(x="Relative Importance", y="Variable")
```

[image: bar plot reordered]